# Creating Image Carousel in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

How can i create an Carousel of Containers Like the example below?

I looked at Pageview class but this only displays one Container and hides the others. But i want to see the Container partly on the left and right too. Is there anyway to do this in Flutter and how?

Note: The current Container should always stay in the center

[image: Example]

Edit: Darky gave an very good Example but i have one problem with his given code:

> The following ArgumentError was thrown building
> AnimatedBuilder(animation: PageController#fc5f0(one client, offset
> 0.0), dirty, state: _AnimatedState#1ea5c): Invalid argument (lowerLimit): not a number: null –

This gets thrown at the Position where he calls controller.page. Does anyone know how i can fix this?

Comment: value = value<0.0 ? 0.0:value;
    value = value>1.0 ? 1.0:value;

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Actually what you want *is* `PageView`.

`PageView` accept a `PageController` as argument. And that controller possess a `viewportFraction` property (default to 1.0) which represent in percent the main-size of displayed pages.

Which means that with a viewportFraction of 0.5, the main page will be centered. And you'll see half a page on both left and right (if there's one)

Example :

[image: example_gif]

```
class Carroussel extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CarrousselState createState() => new _CarrousselState();
}

class _CarrousselState extends State<Carroussel> {
  PageController controller;
  int currentpage = 0;

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = PageController(
      initialPage: currentpage,
      keepPage: false,
      viewportFraction: 0.5,
    );
  }

  @override
  dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          child: PageView.builder(
              onPageChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  currentpage = value;
                });
              },
              controller: controller,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => builder(index)),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  builder(int index) {
    return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: controller,
      builder: (context, child) {
        double value = 1.0;
        if (controller.position.haveDimensions) {
          value = controller.page - index;
          value = (1 - (value.abs() * .5)).clamp(0.0, 1.0);
        }

        return Center(
          child: SizedBox(
            height: Curves.easeOut.transform(value) * 300,
            width: Curves.easeOut.transform(value) * 250,
            child: child,
          ),
        );
      },
      child: Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        color: index % 2 == 0 ? Colors.blue : Colors.red,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The following ArgumentError was thrown building AnimatedBuilder(animation: PageController#fc5f0(one
 client, offset 0.0), dirty, state: _AnimatedState#1ea5c):
 Invalid argument (lowerLimit): not a number: null

Comment: I got these error if i perfom controller.page i dont understand why

Comment: I avoided the error by catching ArgumentError and setting the value as 1.0.

Comment: You should check if pageController.position.haveDimensions is true before calling pageController.page, otherwise it may throw NPE.

Comment: I don't understand how the animation works. I see that the builder function is called when the PageView is scrolling. But how is this possible? Thanks to the AnimatedBuilder Widget? Or for the controller? ://

Comment: This is working great for me except when I am using it in conjunction with StreamBuilders. When I initially draw my page widget, it does not re-size the left/right, but the moment I interact with it it works perfectly until I re-init the page. Is there any tricks you know of to get the animation builder to trigger without interaction?

Comment: @GabbrIssimo The animation is triggered constantly during the animation process. If you debug through it you should see the value variable constantly changing each frame of the animation, which is used to shrink/grow each of the pages.

Comment: solved my own issue: added "max: 1.0, period: Duration(milliseconds: 1)" to the repeat parameters to force the animation to happen once instantly

Comment: @calebisstupid: Please let us know where to add these values.. coz I am stuck with this now for hours. Thanks.

Comment: @calebisstupid: I would like to see your solution as well, I have tried triggering the animations in several ways but none have worked.

Comment: Hey! Thanks a lot for your explanation and code it worked perfectly for me. I'm just stuck on making the container to dismiss once clicked on it. I have created a new question regarding the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54910418/how-to-remove-a-page-from-page-view-with-a-smooth-animation Hopefully you can help me:)

Comment: Hey just having the initial issue too. The repeat method is located on the AnimationController, but as in the sample code I'm also using a PageController. This one does not have a Repeat method.

Comment: Corrected "pageController" to "controller" --- variable name. Then WORKS like charm  

Comment: I really don't understand the `if (pageController.position.haveDimensions)` part in the `AnimatedBuilder`. Could you please explain to me why did you do that and what did you trying to achieve?

Comment: @RémiRousselet hi, use 0.25 viewportFraction, so i display 5page in viewport, how to animate only small size for 1st left and right page from current page and normal size page for 3 other (0(normal), 1(small), 2/currentpage(normal), 3(small), 4(normal))

Comment: @RémiRousselet if I widgets to each box, you can I scale the content of each page to fit and to prevent them from overflowing? thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Thank you for this solution! Is it possible to shrink the font size of the inactive pages?

Comment: @RémiRousselet can you please help me here https://stackoverflow.com/q/61073304/8112541

Comment: @RémiRousselet is there a way to animate fontSize?

Comment: Why is `value` being computed twice in the same block?

Comment: Hi how do you change the padding between the cards ?

Answer (score 4):

This solved my problem:

```
Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 20), () {

  setState(() {
    _pageController.animateToPage(0, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1), curve: Curves.bounceIn);
  });

});
```

Comment: Solved it for me too. I think the above solution using the AnimationController is good, but not sure how to integrate it into the sample as it is using a PageController

Answer (score 0):

Didn't had much time to investigate, but the `AnimatedBuilder` is called `X` times equal to number of visible `children`. Dimensions are not available during first frame, so `controller.page` will throw `Exception`. Correct formula to compute animation offsets during first frame is (caution: it just worked for me flawlessly, keep your implementation in mind):

```
        builder: (context, child) {
          double value = _controller.position.haveDimensions
              ? _controller.page! - index
              : index.toDouble();
          value =  Curves.easeInOut.transform(
              (1 - (value.abs() * .4)).clamp(0.0, 1.0)
          );

          return Center(
            child: Container(
              height: value * widget.height,
              width: value * widget.width,
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
              child: child,
            ),
          );
        },
```