# Horizontally scrollable cards with Snap effect in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation, flutter-sliver

I want to create a list of cards scrolling horizontally with snap to fit effect when swiped either from left or right.

Each card has some spacing between them and fit to screen similar to below image

[image]

Apart from that these horizontally scrollable list elements should be contained inside a vertically scrollable list.

I all I am able to achieve is only displaying a list of horizontal scrolling  cards after following example in flutter docs.

```
class SnapCarousel extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final title = 'Horizontal List';

    return MaterialApp(
      title: title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(title),
        ),
        body: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0),
          height: 200.0,
          child: ListView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                width: 160.0,
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
              Container(
                width: 160.0,
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
              Container(
                width: 160.0,
                color: Colors.green,
              ),
              Container(
                width: 160.0,
                color: Colors.yellow,
              ),
              Container(
                width: 160.0,
                color: Colors.orange,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating Image Carousel in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47349784/creating-image-carousel-in-flutter)

Comment: @RémiRousselet Above link partially solves my issue as I also wanted to put them inside a vertically scrollable list.
Each component inside vertically scrollable list will be a collection of elements which will scroll horizontally.

Comment: Nothing prevents you from doing it with the previous link

Comment: @RémiRousselet can you please provide a basic example of it I don't know how to make it vertically scrollable.

Comment: You don't make it vertically scrollable. Wrap it inside a `ListView` instead

Comment: You can find a similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67534858/9467181)

Answer (score 120, accepted):

Use `PageView` and `ListView`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyHomePage()));

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Carousel in vertical scrollable'),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          if(index % 2 == 0) {
            return _buildCarousel(context, index ~/ 2);
          }
          else {
            return Divider();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildCarousel(BuildContext context, int carouselIndex) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text('Carousel $carouselIndex'),
        SizedBox(
          // you may want to use an aspect ratio here for tablet support
          height: 200.0,
          child: PageView.builder(
            // store this controller in a State to save the carousel scroll position
            controller: PageController(viewportFraction: 0.8),
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int itemIndex) {
              return _buildCarouselItem(context, carouselIndex, itemIndex);
            },
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildCarouselItem(BuildContext context, int carouselIndex, int itemIndex) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4.0),
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.grey,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4.0)),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: first page has some padding ..how to remove that

Comment: pages are centered in the widget. you can increase the `viewportFraction` to 1.0 to make the pages full width.

Comment: I want to achieve something like this https://ibb.co/GcPp3bd. viewportFraction  1.0 make the full screen

Comment: Did you find a way @RahulDevanavar ?

Comment: I tried running this code it simply looks like a Horizontal List View How do we add a zoom effect on current card as shown in the above image of this question

Comment: I don't understand why you needed to nest in `ListView.builder`.

Comment: @ShababbKarim It helps by rendering/building only when necessary, which helps with larger lists or with infinite ones.

Answer (score 103):

#### Output (without using any package):

[image]

---

#### Solution: 1 (using `ListenableBuilder`)

```dart
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  final PageController _controller = PageController(viewportFraction: 0.8);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SizedBox(
        height: 100, // Card height
        child: PageView.builder(
          itemCount: 10,
          controller: _controller,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return ListenableBuilder(
              listenable: _controller,
              builder: (context, child) {
                double factor = 1;
                if (_controller.position.hasContentDimensions) {
                  factor = 1 - (_controller.page! - index).abs();
                }

                return Center(
                  child: SizedBox(
                    height: 70 + (factor * 30),
                    child: Card(
                      elevation: 4,
                      child: Center(child: Text('Card $index')),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

---

#### Solution: 2 (using `AnimatedPadding`)

```dart
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  int _index = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SizedBox(
        height: 100, // Card height
        child: PageView.builder(
          itemCount: 10,
          controller: PageController(viewportFraction: 0.8),
          onPageChanged: (index) => setState(() => _index = index),
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return AnimatedPadding(
              duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
              curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(_index == index ? 0.0 : 8.0),
              child: Card(
                elevation: 4,
                child: Center(child: Text('Card $index')),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This is great! But I'm left wondering, how do you set the distance between items? I wanted a smaller gap?

Comment: @PrimeByDesign Update `scale` value from `0.9` to `0.95`

Comment: when loading itself there is margin in the left, how to remove that?

Comment: @NifalNizar Which margin are you talking about?

Comment: I'm getting a small white space before the first item
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1m3SC7mpLd6tx2iPoMMoMnLCSoUURqCSx/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @NifalNizar I need access to view the file. Can you make that public?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1m3SC7mpLd6tx2iPoMMoMnLCSoUURqCSx/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @NifalNizar Alright, so you're talking about the initial spacing, well I need to tweak few things here and there, currently not able to work for last few days, let me get back to the machine in a day or so, I'll update the solution

Comment: @CopsOnRoad thanks, how can we have multiple items around center item? in your implementation we have only one item, how can we could have for example 2 item?

and changing opacity like screen shot which post owner attached?

Comment: @DolDurma You can set `viewportFraction` to something like `0.5`, and also reduce the `scale` value but then it will not serve the purpose for a `PageView`. For your case, I'll suggest you to use a horizontal `ListView`. And for opacity, simply wrap the `Card` widget inside an `Opacity` widget and set `opacity: i == _index ? 1 : 0.5`

Comment: Any answer of NifalNizar question? @CopsOnRoad?

Comment: can one use a PageView in this context without a fixed height, more like it should wrap it's content.

Comment: How can i make each card display different texts??

Comment: This is stellar mate for an image picker, thank you very much

Comment: If you want to add animation when the card is focused and when the card is shrink, u can see my answer here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75495436/11451151)

Comment: @NifalNizar very late here, but to remove the starting left margin, add `padEnds: false` to the PageView

Answer (score 36):

To achieve the snap effect via ListView, just set the physics to PageScrollPhysics

```
const List<Widget> children = [
  ContainerCard(),
  ContainerCard(),
  ContainerCard(),
];
ListView.builder(
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    physics: const PageScrollPhysics(), // this for snapping
    itemCount: children.length,
    itemBuilder: (_, index) => children[index],
  )
```

Answer (score 33):

this is an old question, and I arrived here looking for something else ;-), but what WitVault was lookig is done easy with this package: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_swiper

[image: Demo image]

**The implementation:**

Put the dependencies in pubsec.yaml:

```
dependencies:
   flutter_swiper: ^1.1.6
```

Import it in the page where you need it:

```
import 'package:flutter_swiper/flutter_swiper.dart';
```

In the layout:

```
new Swiper(
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    return new Image.network(
      "http://via.placeholder.com/288x188",
      fit: BoxFit.fill,
    );
  },
  itemCount: 10,
  viewportFraction: 0.8,
  scale: 0.9,
)
```

Comment: We tried this package. Experience was below expectations for us. Probably because of the large amount of unresolved issues (158 issues at the time of writing - mostly "help wanted"). https://github.com/best-flutter/flutter_swiper/issues  -- we settled for another solution.

Comment: @AlexJean please share the other solution with the community

Comment: PageView as indicated in the duplicate of this question is what we settled for. Other solutions in this post and its duplicate were comfortable as well. Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47349784/creating-image-carousel-in-flutter

Comment: As there seems to be interest - we also used successfully this popular package https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider that has so far not been mentioned among the answers.

Comment: It looks like `flutter_swiper` is not maintained (not even null safety). Found a new fork of it named [card_swiper](https://pub.dev/packages/card_swiper), it is a little bit newer.

Comment: @GuyLuz or you can do it yourself without package. check my answer here [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75495436/11451151)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

---

I believe the answer [solution from CopsOnRoad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60456937/11451151) is better and simple for someone who don't want to use a 3rd party library. **However, since there is no animation, I add the scale animation when the card is viewed (expand) and the previous card is swiped (shrink) using index**. So what happened is whenever the first time the page load, 1st and 2nd card won't have any animation, and when the card is swiped, only the previous and current card have the scale animation. So this is my implementation:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {


const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int currentIndex = -1, previousIndex = 0;

  double getAnimationValue(int currentIndex, int widgetIndex, int previousIndex,
      {bool begin = true}) {
    if (widgetIndex == currentIndex) {
      return begin ? 0.9 : 1;
    } else {
      return begin ? 1 : 0.9;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(
            height: 200, // card height
            child: PageView.builder(
              itemCount: 10,
              controller: PageController(viewportFraction: 0.7),
              onPageChanged: (int index) {
                setState(() {
                  if (currentIndex != -1) {
                    previousIndex = currentIndex;
                  }
                  currentIndex = index;
                });
              },
              itemBuilder: (_, widgetIndex) {
                return (currentIndex != -1 &&
                        (previousIndex == widgetIndex ||
                            widgetIndex == currentIndex))
                    ? TweenAnimationBuilder(
                        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
                        tween: Tween<double>(
                          begin: getAnimationValue(
                            currentIndex,
                            widgetIndex,
                            previousIndex,
                          ),
                          end: getAnimationValue(
                            currentIndex,
                            widgetIndex,
                            previousIndex,
                            begin: false,
                          ),
                        ),
                        builder: (context, value, child) {
                          return Transform.scale(
                            scale: value,
                            child: Card(
                              elevation: 6,
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                              child: Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: [
                                  Text(
                                    "Card${widgetIndex + 1}",
                                    style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
                                  ),
                                  Text(
                                    "$widgetIndex >> Widget Index << $widgetIndex",
                                    style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 22),
                                  ),
                                  Text(
                                    "$currentIndex >> Current Index << $currentIndex",
                                    style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 22),
                                  ),
                                  Text(
                                    "$previousIndex >> Previous Index << $previousIndex",
                                    style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 22),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      )
                    : Transform.scale(
                        // this is used when you want to disable animation when initialized the page
                        scale:
                            (widgetIndex == 0 && currentIndex == -1) ? 1 : 0.9,
                        child: Card(
                          elevation: 6,
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                "Card${widgetIndex + 1}",
                                style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
                              ),
                              Text(
                                "$widgetIndex >> Widget Index << $widgetIndex",
                                style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 22),
                              ),
                              Text(
                                "$currentIndex >> Init Index << $currentIndex",
                                style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 22),
                              ),
                              Text(
                                "$previousIndex >> Previous Index << $previousIndex",
                                style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 22),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I used TweenAnimationBuilder for this animation and hardcoded the widget. You can use method for your widget or use package [flutter_animate](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_animate) for easy animation whenever necessary.

Answer (score 1):

If all of your items are of the same width, you can use these custom scroll physics I wrote, which is based on `PageScrollPhysics`.

It also accounts for overscrolling, rapid scrolling, element centering, and the horizontal padding of the `ListView` which should be equal to the padding between the items.

```
class _SnapPageScrollPhysics extends ScrollPhysics {
  const _SnapPageScrollPhysics({
    super.parent,
    required this.elementWidth,
    required this.elementPadding,
  });

  final double elementWidth;
  final double elementPadding;

  @override
  _SnapPageScrollPhysics applyTo(ScrollPhysics? ancestor) {
    return _SnapPageScrollPhysics(
      parent: buildParent(ancestor),
      elementWidth: elementWidth,
      elementPadding: elementPadding,
    );
  }

  double _getTargetPixels(
    ScrollMetrics position,
    Tolerance tolerance,
    double velocity,
  ) {
    final pageWidth = elementWidth + elementPadding;
    final page = position.pixels / pageWidth + velocity / 3000;
    final offset = (position.viewportDimension - elementWidth) / 2;
    final target = page.roundToDouble() * pageWidth - offset + elementPadding;
    return max(0, min(target, position.maxScrollExtent));
  }

  @override
  Simulation? createBallisticSimulation(
    ScrollMetrics position,
    double velocity,
  ) {
    // If we're out of range and not headed back in range, defer to the parent
    // ballistics, which should put us back in range at a page boundary.
    if ((velocity <= 0.0 && position.pixels <= position.minScrollExtent) ||
        (velocity >= 0.0 && position.pixels >= position.maxScrollExtent)) {
      return super.createBallisticSimulation(position, velocity);
    }
    final tolerance = toleranceFor(position);
    final target = _getTargetPixels(position, tolerance, velocity);
    if (target != position.pixels) {
      return ScrollSpringSimulation(
        spring,
        position.pixels,
        target,
        velocity,
        tolerance: tolerance,
      );
    }
    return null;
  }

  @override
  bool get allowImplicitScrolling => false;
}
```

For example:

```
ListView.separated(
  physics: _SnapPageScrollPhysics(
    elementPadding: padding,
    elementWidth: _width,
  ),
  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: padding),
  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
  itemBuilder: itemBuilder,
  itemCount: itemCount,
  separatorBuilder: (context, index) => SizedBox(width: padding),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

**Advanced Snap List**

If you are looking for advanced usages, such as dynamic item sizes, configurable snap points, visualization of items, and essential control (such as scrollToIndex, animate) you should use the native-based [SnappyListView](https://pub.dev/packages/snappy_list_view) with way more features.

```
SnappyListView(
  itemCount: Colors.accents.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return Container(
        height: 100,
        color: Colors.accents.elementAt(index),
        child: Text("Index: $index"),
    ),
);
```

Comment: Hi Paul, You know if this package provides a vertical axis? Thanks

Comment: Yes! This native-based package will provide you with everything and more you would expect from ListView/PageView (Disclaimer: I am the main developer of this package)

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for solution how to do it wit List without paging

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a `ListView`, and your items are of fixed with, you can use an implementation of `ScrollPhysics` based on `PageScrollPhysics` used by the `PageView`.
This has the limitation that it only works for equally sized children.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SnapScrollPhysics extends ScrollPhysics {
  const SnapScrollPhysics({super.parent, required this.snapSize});

  final double snapSize;

  @override
  SnapScrollSize applyTo(ScrollPhysics? ancestor) {
    return SnapScrollSize(parent: buildParent(ancestor), snapSize: snapSize);
  }

  double _getPage(ScrollMetrics position) {
    return position.pixels / snapSize;
  }

  double _getPixels(ScrollMetrics position, double page) {
    return page * snapSize;
  }

  double _getTargetPixels(
      ScrollMetrics position, Tolerance tolerance, double velocity) {
    double page = _getPage(position);
    if (velocity < -tolerance.velocity) {
      page -= 0.5;
    } else if (velocity > tolerance.velocity) {
      page += 0.5;
    }
    return _getPixels(position, page.roundToDouble());
  }

  @override
  Simulation? createBallisticSimulation(
      ScrollMetrics position, double velocity) {
    // If we're out of range and not headed back in range, defer to the parent
    // ballistics, which should put us back in range at a page boundary.
    if ((velocity <= 0.0 && position.pixels <= position.minScrollExtent) ||
        (velocity >= 0.0 && position.pixels >= position.maxScrollExtent)) {
      return super.createBallisticSimulation(position, velocity);
    }
    final Tolerance tolerance = this.tolerance;
    final double target = _getTargetPixels(position, tolerance, velocity);
    if (target != position.pixels) {
      return ScrollSpringSimulation(spring, position.pixels, target, velocity,
          tolerance: tolerance);
    }
    return null;
  }

  @override
  bool get allowImplicitScrolling => false;
}
```

You can see it in action here:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        physics: SnapScrollPhysics(snapSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/3),
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/3,
            color: Colors.amber[900],
            child: const Center(child: Text('Entry A')),
          ),
          Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/3,
            color: Colors.amber[800],
            child: const Center(child: Text('Entry B')),
          ),
          Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/3,
            color: Colors.amber[700],
            child: const Center(child: Text('Entry C')),
          ),
          Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/3,
            color: Colors.amber[600],
            child: const Center(child: Text('Entry D')),
          ),
          Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/3,
            color: Colors.amber[500],
            child: const Center(child: Text('Entry E')),
          ),
          Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/3,
            color: Colors.amber[400],
            child: const Center(child: Text('Entry F')),
          ),
          Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/3,
            color: Colors.amber[300],
            child: const Center(child: Text('Entry G')),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


class SnapScrollSize extends ScrollPhysics {
  const SnapScrollSize({super.parent, required this.snapSize});

  final double snapSize;

  @override
  SnapScrollSize applyTo(ScrollPhysics? ancestor) {
    return SnapScrollSize(parent: buildParent(ancestor), snapSize: snapSize);
  }

  double _getPage(ScrollMetrics position) {
    return position.pixels / snapSize;
  }

  double _getPixels(ScrollMetrics position, double page) {
    return page * snapSize;
  }

  double _getTargetPixels(
      ScrollMetrics position, Tolerance tolerance, double velocity) {
    double page = _getPage(position);
    if (velocity < -tolerance.velocity) {
      page -= 0.5;
    } else if (velocity > tolerance.velocity) {
      page += 0.5;
    }
    return _getPixels(position, page.roundToDouble());
  }

  @override
  Simulation? createBallisticSimulation(
      ScrollMetrics position, double velocity) {
    // If we're out of range and not headed back in range, defer to the parent
    // ballistics, which should put us back in range at a page boundary.
    if ((velocity <= 0.0 && position.pixels <= position.minScrollExtent) ||
        (velocity >= 0.0 && position.pixels >= position.maxScrollExtent)) {
      return super.createBallisticSimulation(position, velocity);
    }
    final Tolerance tolerance = this.tolerance;
    final double target = _getTargetPixels(position, tolerance, velocity);
    if (target != position.pixels) {
      return ScrollSpringSimulation(spring, position.pixels, target, velocity,
          tolerance: tolerance);
    }
    return null;
  }

  @override
  bool get allowImplicitScrolling => false;
}
```