# I need an App screen where I have A Grid of Icons (Clickable), A banner and a list view of items

Tags: android, user-interface, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

[image: APP screen]

Like the above example, I mentioned is there any way to achieve it, since the Bottom navigation bar is fixed, on clicking the icon page should be loaded and scrollable without affecting the navigation bar?

Comment: this might help, this just shows navigation bar and not bottom nav. https://medium.com/@kashifmin/flutter-setting-up-a-navigation-drawer-with-multiple-fragments-widgets-1914fda3c8a8

Comment: No, not a navigation drawer, My main concern is the bottom navigation with the App page

Comment: I understand, I am saying use the same concept that way the scaffold wont change and the bottom nav will stay the same

Comment: check this video. this will be of some use https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=31WHkRuMuPw

Comment: i did the same for tabview change but how can i achieve the App Page having Grid , Banner and list view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have SingleChildScrollView as a parent and use shrinkWrap=true in inside lists and grids,

```
SingleChildScrollView(
   child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[

     GridView(
     physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
     shrinkWrap: true, // use it
     ),

     CarouselSlider(...),

     ListView.builder(
      shrinkWrap: true, // use it
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,// this will make your list horizontal scrollable
    )
   ],
  ),
));
```

For CarouselSlider you can use [this library](https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider#-readme-tab-).

Comment: No Carousel Slider, but In listView how can I add the Image and icon on it

Comment: Are you talking about 'Trending' listview or banner slider? for slider [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51612288/5734205) might help. If you are talking about Trending listview section then please let me know I will update my answer.

Comment: a Normal list view with banner and grid view is all that I need in a scroll view

Comment: You can check my [gist](https://gist.github.com/raviganwal/60b331a8080a2a88e7977a232c50f943) and you can also take inspiration from [mixed-list](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/lists/mixed-list)