# jumping to another page in PageView() not working

Tags: dart, flutter

I have following pageview()

```
Widget _build() {
    return PageView(
        children:<Widget>[
            page1,
            page2,
            page3
        ]
    )
}
```

now when this _build method is called i want to show page2  and not initial page.

I have tried this code

```
initState(){
    pageController = PageController();
    pageController.jumpToPage(2);
}
```

but here 2nd line throws this error

`ScrollController not attached to any scroll views`

how can i show a particular page using PageView() ?
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's what i did
to show a particular page we have to pass its index to `PageController` constructor
like this
`pageController = PageController(initialPage: widget.activePageIndex);`

Answer (score 2):

You must have a PageController linked with your PageView, and in your PageController there is a property "initialPage".

See this good example: [Creating Image Carousel in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47349784/creating-image-carousel-in-flutter)

Comment: hi thanks for answering.  but this is not working in initState() it throws error only when it is inside initState()