# Flutter horizontal scrollable listview pop up effect

Tags: listview, flutter, scrollable

I figured out how to make a `horizontal` scrollable list. 
But i am trying figure out to make the item coming to the center have popupup effect.

[image]

I am trying to make a ui similar to refecty app Scrolling cards

Any input will be appreciate! 
Thanks

Comment: Please add your current code in the question to help understand your problem better.

Comment: this might be helpful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SGLyKxTAo00

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating Image Carousel in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47349784/creating-image-carousel-in-flutter)

Comment: a flutter team member create a package to achieve this, check it out : https://github.com/efortuna/coverflow .