# How to remove a page from Page View with a smooth animation?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I'm still new to flutter animation, and I'm trying to make a PageView to dismiss when you press on it with an animation.

I have this code:

```
class Carroussel extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CarrousselState createState() => new _CarrousselState();
}

class _CarrousselState extends State<Carroussel> {
  PageController controller;
  int currentpage = 0;

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = new PageController(
      initialPage: currentpage,
      keepPage: false,
      viewportFraction: 0.5,
    );
  }

  @override
  dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new Center(
        child: new Container(
          child: new PageView.builder(
              onPageChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  currentpage = value;
                });
              },
              controller: controller,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => builder(index)),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  builder(int index) {
    return new AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: controller,
      builder: (context, child) {
        double value = 1.0;
        if (pageController.position.haveDimensions) {
          value = controller.page - index;
          value = (1 - (value.abs() * .5)).clamp(0.0, 1.0);
        }

        return new Center(
          child: new SizedBox(
            height: Curves.easeOut.transform(value) * 300,
            width: Curves.easeOut.transform(value) * 250,
            child: child,
          ),
        );
      },
      child: new Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        color: index % 2 == 0 ? Colors.blue : Colors.red,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

*Author of the above code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47357960/1194779*

That Produces the following:
[image]

Now I need to make it once I press on a card to be dismissed with an animation.

I have tried implementing SlideTransition that slides the card downwards. But I'm failing to make the PageView to animate the filling empty space of the just removed card.

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Comment: Same, any news on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Dismissible` to enable swipe gestures on your widget. Though when used with PageViews, Dismissible creates a jank that may be undesirable.

```dart
class Carousel extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CarouselState createState() => _CarouselState();
}

class _CarouselState extends State<Carousel>{
  late PageController controller;
  int currentPage = 0;
  List<String> listItem = ['Page 1', 'Page 2', 'Page 3', 'Page 4'];

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = PageController(
      initialPage: currentPage,
      keepPage: false,
      viewportFraction: 0.5,
    );
  }

  @override
  dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          child: PageView.builder(
            itemCount: listItem.length,
            onPageChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
                currentPage = value;
              });
            },
            controller: controller,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                pageBuilder(index),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  pageBuilder(int index) {
    var dismissibleKey = GlobalKey<State>();
    return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: controller,
      builder: (context, child) {
        double value = 1.0;
        if (controller.position.haveDimensions) {
          value = controller.page! - index;
          value = (1 - (value.abs() * .5)).clamp(0.0, 1.0);
        }

        return Center(
          child: SizedBox(
            height: Curves.easeOut.transform(value) * 300,
            width: Curves.easeOut.transform(value) * 250,
            child: child,
          ),
        );
      },
      child: Dismissible(
        key: dismissibleKey,
        direction: DismissDirection.down,
        onDismissed: (DismissDirection direction) {
          /// Remove item from List
          setState(() {
            listItem.removeAt(index);
          });
        },
        child: InkWell(
          onLongPress: () {
            debugPrint('Delete! $index');
            setState(() {
              listItem.removeAt(index);
            });
          },
          onTap: () {
            controller.animateToPage(index,
                duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500), curve: Curves.ease);
          },
          child: Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            // color: index % 2 == 0 ? Colors.blue : Colors.red,
            color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
            child: Center(
              child: Text('${listItem[index]}'),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Demo]